# Map points shifted after update from 3.8.3-Zanzibar to 3.34.1-Prizen

Tags: qgis, well-known-text

I'm in the process of setting up a new laptop, so need to migrate my QGIS project to the new computer.  It's been a while since I've updated QGIS so the old computer is running 3.8.3-Zanzibar. The new laptop has 3.34.1-Prizen.

When I open the project on the new computer it prompts me to "Select a translation" for one of the layers

[image: Map translation pop-up]

I've selected the first option, assuming it's the most accurate.

This may be completely unrelated, but the layers of the project no longer line up.  Here is a screen shot from the new computer.
[image: 3.34.1]

The red lines should line up with the black property outlines.

Here's what it looks like on the old computer
[image: 3.8.3]

Any suggestions on why the layers no longer align and how to correct the offset?
I've looked at the Project and Layer CRS on both computers and can't see anything obvious.

---

**07/01/2024**

Additional information, following the feedback on the translation files.

I've had a search through the QGIS installations and also the data directory for the project.

- There are a number of .tif files in the data directory - these appear to relate to specific map tiles that I've bought and downloaded and a graphic files / images rather than translation files
- QGIS 3.8 does not have any .tif files in the installation
- QGIS 3.34.1 has a large number of .tif files, including the one mentioned (uk_os_OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.tif)

---

This may be a red herring, however if I check the Project Properties on both computers

**QGIS 3.8.3**
Under the CRS menu item, there is a section on Datum Transformations
[image]

**QGIS 3.34.1**
The Project Properties menus have been updated. It looks like the Datum Transformations have been moved to their own menu item where I can see
[image]

---

**10/01/2024**
A further update to this question.

I believe I've tracked down the problem to the the CRS definitions for each layer.

Here is an example of the CRS for one of the problem layers:

Legacy Project String:
`+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs`

WKT:

```
GEOGCRS["unknown",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ID["EPSG",6326]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8901]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]]
```

If I select one of the predefined CRS the layer disappears off my map, so it looks like I need to edit the CRS definition to add the required offset.
To get the layer to line up I need to move it approx 3m North and 1m East

How can I edit the WKT file (or the Legacy Project String) to achieve this?

Comment: I believe that you should select the same transformation that was used in the old computer. The transformation that you selected now is probably utilizing a grid shift file `uk_os_OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.tif`. Do you have that on both computer?

Comment: I've had a search through the QGIS installations and also the data directory for the project.
There are a number of .tif files in the data directory - these appear to relate to specific map tiles that I've bought and downloaded.
QGIS 3.8 does not have any .tif files in the installation
QGIS 3.34.1 has a large number of .tif files, including the one that you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

So... after much experimentation I've given up on trying to correct the CRS and simply moved all the features on the layer so they lined up with the other layers.  Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best.

Here are the steps I've taken

- Select the layer I want to move
- Put the layer in edit mode
- Select all items in the layer (Ctrl-A)
- On the "Edit" menu, select "Edit Geometry" - "Move Features"

[image]

- Select a feature from those in the layer I need to move
- QGIS shows a wireframe of the features as you move them
- Click on the new location
- Save the changes to the layer
- Turn off the layer edit mode